# React router, how to redirect a route to its sub route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How to redirect a route to its sub route? The `'/charts'` route doesn't have some component to show, but its sub routes, `'/charts/:itemId'`, each has a different chart to display. How can I redirect the route to its first sub route? What I did is directly use `<Redirect />`, but get an error showing at the end:

My react Component's render method:

```
render() {
<Router>
...
 <div id='content' className='col-md-10 container'>
              <Redirect from="/charts" to="/charts/item_1"/>
              <Route path="/charts/:categoryId" component={MyChart} />
            </div>
...
</Router>
}
```

This will give error:

```
index.js:2178 Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "/charts/:itemId"
```

Comment: I would define your routes together higher up the component chain, like in an App component so they stay organized. Your `<Redirect />` component should only render when you want to redirect them. So you need to apply that conditionally. Read the docs and look for examples. Generally, if I'm using `<Redirect />` it's the only thing that renders. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Redirect` without the `exact` keyword or `Switch`, in which case everytime you Redirect to `"/charts/:categoryId"`, it matches `/charts` and hence redirects again, you can either use `exact` prop like

```
render() {
    return(
        <Router>
        ...
         <div id='content' className='col-md-10 container'>
                      <Redirect exact from="/charts" to="/charts/item_1"/>
                      <Route path="/charts/:categoryId" component={MyChart} />
                    </div>
        ...
        </Router>
    )
}
```

or use Switch

```
render() {
    return(
        <Router>
        ...
         <div id='content' className='col-md-10 container'>
                   <Switch>
                      <Route path="/charts/:categoryId" component={MyChart} />
                      <Redirect from="/charts" to="/charts/item_1"/>
                   </Switch>
                    </div>
        ...
        </Router>
    )
}
```